# C# inline if or value syntax

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

Does C# have something like the JavaScript if or value syntax?

For example, I know you can do this in JavaScript:

```
var test = someValue || thisValue;
```

if **someValue** is undefined, false, or empty string, then test becomes **thisValue**. However, I've never seen a way to do this in C# other than a traditional if, or inline if.

Comment: Thanks for all of the great responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NullCoalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
var test = someValue ?? thisValue;
```

However, C# doesn't do weird JavaScript falsey behaviors.

The short circuit evaluation in C# is more pertinent in evaulating bools:

```
private bool EvaluateA()
{
    return true;
}

private bool EvaluateB()
{
    return false;
}

public static int main()
{
    Console.Write(EvaluateA() || EvaluateB()); // EvaluateB is never called
}
```

Comment: You need to make it an OR, otherwise, `EvaluateB()` will still be called.
Or make EvaluateA() `return false;` then `EvaluateB()` will never be called.

Comment: There is also the `ternary` operator which might be useful for the OP.

Comment: T || (Anyhting, either True or False) == True, F && (Anything, either T or F) is false.  Short Circuit means, it will evaluate the first parameter, if it has all it needs to return a result, it will not evaluate the second parameter at all.

Answer (score 2):

Its called the null-coalescing operator.

```
String someValue = null;
var thisValue = "Foo";
var test = someValue ?? thisValue;
// test will be == "Foo"
```

As mentioned in the comments, this doesn't work for empty strings, "false", etc.  What you can do in C# is write an extension method to do that, if you really want to:

```
public static class MyStringThing {
    public static String FixErUp(this String s1, String s2) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s1) || s1.Equals("false"))
            return s2;
        return s1;
    }
}
```

to be used like so:

```
String someValue = "false";
var thisValue = "Foo";
var test = someValue.FixErUp(thisValue);
// test will be == "Foo"
```

Comment: To note - this only works for null instances and does not work for false/empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `??`

```
var test = someValue ?? thisValue;
```

This only works if `someValue` is null.  To check for `false` or `string.Empty`, you'll need to use a normal `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  But it does have null coalescing.

Given a reference type, you could have the value or an alternative if it is `null`.

```
string foo = null;
string value = foo ?? "bar"; // value == "bar"
```

Otherwise for any other case (i.e., non-null, all whitespace, value type, etc.), you'll have to do other forms of checking.

```
string foo = "";
string value1 = foo ?? "bar"; // value1 == ""
string value2 = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo) ? foo : "bar"; // value1 == "bar"
```